"an denen ist etwas dran", why not "sind" (instead of ist)
On english wiktionary I came across this example:

„Was hältst Du von den Gerüchten?“ — „Ich denke, an denen ist etwas dran.“


"What do you make of the rumours?" — "I think there might be something to them."

But AFAIK "denen" is third person plural which would require "sind". Or do I miss something?

Yes, you missed something. Think again about what the subject of the sentence is.

@RHa after posting this it stroke me that maybe "etwas" is the subject, but I'm not that sure about that. An explaination why "etwas" is the subject (if that's the case) could be useful. To me it's a bit odd to place the subject after the verb, but then I'm not german.

German word order is flexible, so sometimes the subject appears after the verb. The main rule is that the verb is second, but you can pick and choose which sentence element comes first. Also, "an denen" isn't a noun or noun phrase, so it really can't be the subject anyway. I'm not sure why Wiktionary has "Du" capitalized; is it wrong or is there something I'm missing?

@RDBury Maybe this helps with the question regarding Du/du.

Btw, the verb "sein" can be tricky for English speakers in general. It takes two nouns in the nominative case, and you can't go by word order, so it can be hard to tell what the correct conjugation should be. You can say "Ich bin ein Berliner," or "Ein Berliner bin ich," but "Ein Berliner ist ich," just sounds wrong to me; I can't tell you why.

@Olafant - So "Du" isn't always wrong, but still I don't see it being correct in an example like this. It's not a quotation, and it seems more like a recorded conversation than a letter. If there are no objections I'll fix it.

@rdbury A lot of people still retain the older, uppercase "Du" over the lower-case, probably more correct spelling of today- Just because it used to somehow transport appreciation and respect. In most cases, I would suppose, that's a case of deliberately breaking the rules to try and be nice (People, - including myself, sometimes - tend to be stubborn).

@RDBury: re ein Berliner bin ich would be a great question (I haven't bothered to look, maybe already asked) and you should ask it - I will answer it in detail if you do.

@bakunin - I think https://german.stackexchange.com/q/7631/43989 covers a lot of the issue, and I already have kind of an ear for what sounds right.  I usually only ask if there's some actual German speech/writing I'm puzzled by, not if it's just an example I made up.

You confused the subject and a prepositional object.

An diesem Ding ist nur der Name ungewöhnlich.

About this thing, only the name is unusual.
See what I did here? I used the topic in the English translation. This because it’s exactly what the first thing in a German main clause is: the topic. The subject goes behind the conjugated verb.
Only if the subject is the topic, you move it to the front:

Nur der Name ist an diesem Ding ungewöhnlich.

Only the name is unusual about this thing.
This is a general rule in German main clauses. All main clauses are topicalized by default. If you don’t want a topic, you need an expletive:

Es ist an diesem Ding nur der Name ungewöhnlich.
Es ist nur der Name an diesem Ding ungewöhnlich.

Only the name is unusual about this thing.
In English this case cannot be told apart from the case when the subject is the topic.

And it’s the same for your example:

An denen ist etwas dran.

About them, something is fancy/strong/elaborated.

Etwas ist an denen dran.

Something is fancy/strong/elaborated about them.

Es ist an denen etwas dran
Es ist etwas an denen dran.

Something is fancy/strong/elaborated about them
